# Plot non uniform interval axis

Tags: r

I am attempting to reproduce the Fry Graph (see below) in base graphics and eventually plot numeric valued points on that graph.
[image]

This graph contains uneven intervals on the y axis.  I gather from other posts on here that I need to enter the `labels` in as characters but I can't seem to get it correct.  I have two problems I need help with:

1. How to I correctly plot the labels (Y) on the y axis
2. Later when I need to add points (see the end of the code) how will I be able to
       plot  numeric points onto a y axis that is not numeric?

**CODE:**

```
 Y <- c('2.0', '2.5', '3.0', '3.3', '3.5', '3.6', '3.7', '3.8', '4.0', '4.2', '4.3', 
          '4.5', '4.8', '5.0', '5.2', '5.6', '5.9', '6.3', '6.7', '7.1', '7.7', '8.3', 
          '9.1', '10.0', '11.1', '12.5', '14.3', '16.7', '20.0', '20+')

X11(14, 10)
plot(1, 1, xlim=c(108,172), axes=FALSE, type='n', 
    xlab="Average number of syllables per 100 words", 
    ylab="Average number of sentences per 100 words", 
    main="Fry Graph for Estimating Reading Ages (grade level)",
    xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')

axis(1, at = 108:172, labels = TRUE)
axis(2, at = 2:25,  labels=Y)
grid(nx=64, ny=46, lty="solid", col="gold")
grid(nx=32, ny=23, lty="solid", col="gray65")
box()

y <-c(5, 5.9)
x <-c(128, 136)
points(x, y)
```

Comment: I've decided this is too convoluted.  I will reproduce it numerically instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve this discrepancy:

```
> length(Y)
[1] 30
> length(2:25)
[1] 24
```

Then by adding a ylim =range(at-range) argument in the plot call, you should be able to plot "at" whatever you want. At the moment the ylim is being set by the data range of c(1,1).

(And las=2 to rotate the labels:)

```
plot(1, 1, xlim=c(108,172), axes=FALSE, type='n', ylim=c(1,30),
    xlab="Average number of syllables per 100 words", 
    ylab="Average number of sentences per 100 words", 
    main="Fry Graph for Estimating Reading Ages (grade level)",
    xaxs = 'i', yaxs = 'i')

axis(1, at = 108:172, labels = TRUE)
axis(2, at = 1:30,  labels=Y, las=2)
grid(nx=64, ny=46, lty="solid", col="gold")
grid(nx=32, ny=23, lty="solid", col="gray65")
box()
```

[image]